# Uploading and accessing images with Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to upload some static images that I will later access via some mobile apps. I have an Azure Account that I rarely use so I thought that was the best place and therefore I uploaded them to a "File Share" within Azure Storage.

I naievely thought I could them just access those files via a simple web request url

```
https://myplace.file.core.windows.net/app/images/bnb/shop/bugle_200_2.jpg
```

All this gets me is a BadRequest error. I realize that I could create a Shared Access Signature (SAS) for every file but that seems total overkill.

Is there a better Azure feature to use? I do not want to have to use the Azure APIs to get at these files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the service you should be looking to use is blob storage, not file storage.  File storage, as per [the documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/files/), is meant more for SMB shares.

When you setup Azure blob storage, you have a couple of different options.  If there is nothing sensitive/secure about these static images, you could consider making a [public container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-manage-access-to-resources) and simply accessing the files like that.

If you require authentication, then you need to either use azure storage access keys, or azure storage access tokens.  Of the two, the storage access tokens are by far the most secure.

You wouldn't need to create a SAS token for each file, rather, grant it read permission to the container.  Once again, you will have to tailor this to the security/sensitivity needs of your application.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a few more points to @CtrlDot's excellent answer.

I completely agree that you should use `Blob Storage` for storing static content.

On the container permissions, I would actually recommend setting the permission (ACL) to `Blob` so that user can only view the blob they have the URL for and not enumerate all blobs in a container (setting container ACL to `Container` will enable the users to list blobs in a container which may not be a desired behaviour for you).

Other than these, there are two distinct advantage of using Blob Storage:

1. **Custom domain**: You can map blob storage to a custom domain (e.g. static content.mywebsite.com) and use that to serve the content instead of using Azure Blob Storage standard endpoint (your account.blob.core.windows.net).
2. **CDN**: You can also CDN enable your blob storage endpoint. The content will then be replicated across many CDN nodes spread throughout the globe and will be served from a node near to your user thus improving the user experience.